# Splitting a string of 5 digit zipcodes with any delimiter or character?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get an input of multiple zipcodes as a string and split them to see if a record exists for each zipcode in a specific table; I did String_Split for just ',' as a delimiter, but is there a way to do it for any symbol or character placed between each zipcode?

For example '12345 | 12345' or '12345 12345'

```
DECLARE @Zipcodes nvarchar(max) = '78257, 10101, 91111,99999,  11111 222222'    

SELECT * 
FROM BranchWithZipcode 
WHERE zipcode IN (SELECT CAST(Value AS int) 
                  FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(@Zipcodes, ' ', ''), ','))
```

I tried using `PATINDEX` for any 5 digits in a string but it only returned the first index and I couldn't figure out what to do with it

Comment: Do you have a known number of delimiters, or could you receive a mess like `12345a45678|23146^62437$013451!13232/52167-25246+21951.21465 16955` where any non-numeric character is a "delimiter"?

Comment: SQL is a query language, not a text processing language. You'd need a regular expression at least and T-SQL doesn't have regular expressions. If you *must* store zip codes as text, store them as JSON. This way you can use JSON functions to extract the values, no matter what they contain

Comment: I wouldn't say you *need* regex, @PanagiotisKanavos . I have a several (version specific) "helper functions" for replacing characters based on a pattern which would work here. Though if the OP has a known number of delimiters then `TRANSLATE` would be a better solution.

Comment: Where does `@Zipcodes` come from? A query or stored procedure parameter? A table field? Is it hard-coded in a script? It may be possible to use a table-valued parameter to send a list of values to the stored procedure. Or you can create a JSON array on the client which can be easily parsed.

Comment: @ThomA what if there's a space before or after the delimiter? Or more than 5 digits? Or a mix of text, digits and spaces, like English ZIP codes, eg `M60 7LH` ?

Comment: Preferably where any non-numeric character is a delimiter @ThomA

Comment: @Jason where does that data come from? How is it generated? The whitespace in your example suggest this was typed by hand, in which case there's no *fixed* delimiter

Comment: If the OP has anything than non-numerical zip codes, then they are stuffed, @PanagiotisKanavos , I don't disagree.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It comes from a stored procedure parameter where a user could enter a string of 1-n number of zipcodes and I will have to validate if each zipcode has an entry in a table.

Comment: If the value is user entry *why* are you allowing them to enter such nonsense..?

Comment: Users don't call stored procedures directly, applications do it for them. The application could easily clean up the values, trim whitespace and generate a string with eg a JSON array, ie `["11111","1234567",'M60 7LH"]`. The last one is a valid Manchester zip code. It's also possible to create a table-valued parameter and call the stored procedure with a table of zip codes. In C# you could call such a stored procedure with a DataTable parameter

Comment: In eg C#, it's easy to clean up the data and construct a JSON array: `var json=JsonSerializer.Serialize(userSelections.Select(s=>s.Trim()))`. In the stored procedure you can use `OPENJSON(@json)` to parse the JSON string and treat the values as table rows

Answer (score 1):

Provided there is a limited number of potential delimiters this might be as simple as a few nested `REPLACE` functions.

```
DECLARE @Zipcodes nvarchar(max) = '78257, 10101, 91111,99999,  11111 222222|90210&12345'  

SELECT *
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Zipcodes,' ',','),'|',','),'&',','),',')
 WHERE value <> ''
```

| value |
| --- |
| 78257 |
| 10101 |
| 91111 |
| 99999 |
| 11111 |
| 222222 |
| 90210 |
| 12345 |

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to use a helper function to remove the unwanted characters. The helper function below is my version for SQL Server 2022+ and uses `GENERATE_SERIES` and `STRING_AGG`. If you're on 2019 or prior you'll need to replace `GENERATE_SERIES` with a tally (function) and if you're on 2016 or prior you'll need to replace `STRING_AGG` with something like `FOR XML PATH`.

Once you have the helper function, I would `INSERT` the zipcodes into an indexed temporary table, and then use an `EXISTS` against that:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [fn].[PatternNCharacterReplace_MAX] (@String nvarchar(MAX), @Pattern nvarchar(100), @ReplacementCharacter nvarchar(1)) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    --Written by Thom A - https://wp.larnu.uk
    --Licenced under CC-BY-SA

    SELECT STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN V.C LIKE @Pattern THEN @ReplacementCharacter ELSE V.C END,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY GS.value) AS ReplacedString
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(CONVERT(int,LEN(@String)),1) GS
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@String,GS.value,1)))V(C);
GO

DECLARE @Zipcodes nvarchar(MAX) = N'78257, 10101, 91111,99999,  11111 222222';

CREATE TABLE #ZipCodes (ZipCode varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY); --varchar as it's only going to have numerical digits

INSERT INTO #ZipCodes (ZipCode)
SELECT DISTINCT SS.value
FROM fn.PatternNCharacterReplace_MAX(@Zipcodes,'[^0-9]',',') PCR
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(PCR.ReplacedString,',') SS
WHERE SS.value != '';

SELECT <Explicit Column List>
FROM dbo.BranchWithZipcode BWZ
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM #ZipCodes ZC
              WHERE ZC.ZipCode = BWZ.zipcode);
```

---

Though, from your comments, it appears this is actually coming from user input for a stored procedure. If so, then fix the problem by using a table type parameter:

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.ZipCodes AS TABLE(ZipCode varchar(10) /*PRIMARY KEY*/); --If you can ensure that a postcode is only enter once, this would be advantageous so you can have the PK
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.YourProc @ZipCodes dbo.ZipCodes READONLY AS
BEGIN

    SELECT <Explicit Column List>
    FROM dbo.BranchWithZipcode BWZ
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM @ZipCodes ZC
                  WHERE ZC.ZipCode = BWZ.zipcode);
END;
```

Then you can execute the procedure like so:

```sql
DECLARE @ZipCodes dbo.ZipCodes;
INSERT INTO @ZipCodes (ZipCode)
VALUES ('78257'),('10101'),('91111'),('99999'),('11111'),('222222');

EXEC dbo.YourProc @ZipCodes;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rtt0A_9x)